# Flash not displaying in iframe

Tags: html, flash, iframe

I have a flash video player that I would like to embed in other pages, so I created an iframe to do this. It has to be an iframe because it depends on other swf files that get loaded into it (plugins).

The weird thing is the video does not play when loaded inside the iframe, but if I go to the html source and cut and paste the  tag outside of the iframe it works.

```
<iframe width="500px" height="500px" src="http://somedomain.com/embed.aspx" ></iframe>
```

Comment: In every browser? A specific one? Are there any errors on the page (use your browsers' debug tools). Can you provide any source code? Help us help you!

Comment: lol. No errors on the page, happens in every browser. What I just noticed is that it works when I use a fixed width and height for the object tag that resides inside the iframe. If I use percentages it doesn't display...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working by adding come css to the html page containing the flash player. It seems the absolute positioning made all the difference.

```
html, body, object { margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: absolute; height: 100%; width: 100%; overflow: hidden; background-color: #000; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your console. If you are also getting these errors:

"Blocked script execution in '...' because the document's frame is sandboxed and the 'allow-scripts' permission is not set."

You can configure those sandbox flags on the iframe

```
<iframe width="100%" sandbox='allow-scripts allow-same-origin'></iframe>
```